# Smarty kills my session

Tags: php, session, smarty, session-variables, smarty3

I have a problem with Smarty 3.1.13.

Smarty kills my session. Every time I refresh my page, $_SESSION array is empty.
When I comment line `$smarty->display('index.tpl')`, everything is OK.

Any ideas?

Comment: smarty will not kill your session, show your code

Comment: fyi there was a patch release yesterday...

Comment: Which patch? Can you tell something more?
If you mean releaseof Smarty 3.1.13, I downloaded it, and problem still exists.

Comment: Post your code to help you!

Comment: Hi, have you ever solved the issue?

Comment: @Kida unfortunately not. However, I posted an answer here with observation when it happens. Check if it gives you some hints to go. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You have to start your session before `$smarty->display('index.tpl')`

This is beacause the session cookie needs to be send in the HTTP header and therefore [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) will need to be called before the first line of output.

So make sure `session_start()` is placed before `$smarty->display('index.tpl')`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but session is started in the second line of index.php (just after <?php), file encoding UTF-8 without BOM, so any headers can't be send before `session_start()`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post this time code, because it's divided to many parts (framework), and I don't have permissions to publish them.
Thanks for your time, but I found another problem with Smarty and solusion for my problem:

1. When you write templates in extending way (one template extends other), you can't see Smarty debug window, even if `$smaty->debug=true`
2. When your running template is extending another, and `$smarty->debug = true`, it kills your session. Don't ask me why, I didn't have time to check it. I think it's a bug.