# Pass data from smarty to php

Tags: php, session, curl, smarty

Smarty lets you use PHP tags but for some reason session_start does not work in Smarty. I could not find out how.

I can't pull out a session variable in a PHP file from a smarty template.

What I need is very simple. Pass data from Smarty (TPL) to a php file. Same server, same domain, same host. Some people asked this before but exactly the other way around. Notice that I don't want to pass data from PHP to Smarty, but the other way around.

Using get, post or cookies is unsafe and a database would be overkill since all I need is make sure the USER A is still the USER A when he lands on the php page. Sessions are perfect and they are exactly for this, but since I cannot start a php session in Smarty it seems there is no way to connect them together. Using curl with a post command like this was an external page would very overkill, because both pages are in the same server, and both are executing exactly the same php server, so why is this so hard? Something like this should be simple but it seems its not. Not at least without exposing this to the user with get or post.

Does someone know a safe way to do this or connect them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377923/smarty-kills-my-session

Comment: I do start the session at the top but actually what I want to pass to the other page is a variable in that template, so that would not work.

Comment: Writing `PHP` code in `Smarty` templates is not the way to go. The whole reason of existence of template systems is to separate the logic (PHP code) and the presentation (template). The normal flow of information is from PHP code to the template and not the other way around. What data can a Smarty template produce that the PHP code does not already have? Your code is just in the wrong place. Put it into the PHP file and your problem vanishes.